# what is the fastest way to generate random images from a color histogram?

Tags: python, image, colors, pixel

Suppose I have a color histogram. Is there a slick way in python to generate a random image from the color histogram?

More specifically, I want to generate each pixel with a random color according to the distribution of the color histogram.

thanks!

Comment: What is the format of your histogram? I mean can you show us how you have it stored and give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

The arguments, from the linked docs:

> **a** : 1-D array-like or int
>
> If an ndarray, a random sample is generated from its elements. If an
>   int, the random sample is generated as if a were np.arange(a)
>
> **size** : int or tuple of ints, optional
>
> Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k
>   samples are drawn. Default is None, in which case a single value is
>   returned.
>
> **replace** : boolean, optional
>
> Whether the sample is with or without replacement
>
> **p** : 1-D array-like, optional
>
> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given the
>   sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a.

---

The argument `shape` should be the size of your image, e.g., `(100,100)`. The argument `a` should be the distribution, and the argument `p` should be the distribution generated by the histogram.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
bins = np.array([0,0.5,1])
freq = np.array([1.,2,3])
prob = freq / np.sum(freq)
image = np.random.choice(bins, size=(100,100), replace=True, p=prob)
plt.imshow(image)
```

yields

[image: Random image]

---

To support multiple color channels, you have several options. Here is one, where we choose from the color indices instead of the colors themselves:

```
colors = np.array([(255.,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)])
indices = np.array(range(len(colors)))
im_indices = np.random.choice(indices, size=(100,100), p=prob)
image = colors[im_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question though, for colored image, how do we generate color histogram? Since there are three channels, how do we flatten the color range into 1 dimension?

Comment: @jack does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I get the idea but the code to generate a color space with shape (255, 255, 255) is not correct though

Comment: @jack sorry, I'm having trouble parsing the second sentence - did I misunderstand your intent (the code works but does the wrong thing), or does the code not work, or is everything working properly?

Comment: Sorry I meant the colors = np.array([(255.,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255)])
does not generate an array with shape (255, 255, 255). Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, that was an array of three colors (a red, a green, and a blue), just as an example. In the previous example, [0, .5, 1] corresponded to 3 grayscale colors. I assumed the frequences were the same as in the last example. Then, image is an 100x100 image sampled based on the histogram from those three colors. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh I see! That makes sense. But the follow up question I asked was actually how to generate such a color histogram. So for an RGB image, I want to have a histogram that looks like {color1: 0.01, color2: 0.1,..... color100:0.04}, where colorxxx is a color represent a bin that has shape (256, 256, 3). But your answer already answered the question I asked before, so I would select it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Great; SO is already getting mad at me for this long chat convo :) follow up questions are great to make their own question! That way future readers won't get confused if two questions are conflated into one

Answer (score 1):

[random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) can select elements from a weighted population. Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> histogram = {"white": 1, "red": 5, "blue": 10}
>>> pixels = random.choices(list(histogram.keys()), list(histogram.values()), k=25)
>>> pixels
['blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue']
```